# Naming multiple image after cropping

Tags: python

I want to save and name a serial cropped images

with the code

```
for b in range(1, int(Roll)+1):
    count = 1
    for a in range(int(Column)):
        left = a * int(step)
        top = (b - 1) * int(Roll_step)
        right = int(pixel) + a * int(step)
        bottom = int(pixel) + (b - 1) * int(Roll_step)
        im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
        im1.save(f"layer {b}_{count}.jpg")
        count += 1
```

The images that saved will be named as [layer 1_**1**, layer 1_**2**,....layer 1_**10**,....layer 1_**99**, layer 1_**100**]

How to save them as [layer 1_**001**, layer 1_**002**,....layer 1_**010**,....layer 1_**099**, layer 1_**100**]

Answer (score 4):

Format the integer to be zero-padded to a width of three:

```
f"layer {b}_{count:03}.jpg"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `count:03`, since the OP wants `001` and `099` vs `01` and `99`

Comment: @Wondercricket Woopsie, fixed.